# How to step out of a foreach loop in Visual Studio debug mode?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I have a method which I am interested to see it’s functionality and dig deeper into it; so I put a breakpoint and I stepped into the method.

This method executes a foreach loop along the way and this foreach keeps iterating many times. I am not interested in seeing the iteration going on in this foreach loop.

Is there a way in Visual Studio to ”step out of this loop” and continue debugging?

Comment: Good question - I usually just put a break in the next line after the loop and press F5, then remove the breakpoint :-)

Comment: In VS2013, you can just drag and drop the cursor. But that way, the foreach will not all be executed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Right-click on a line after the loop, then click Run to cursor.

Comment: Huh... I never knew there was an option for this... Very useful for not needed to put one-off temporary breakpoints in.

Answer (score 8):

While debugging, put a breakpoint just after your loop and press <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Answer (score 5):

While debugging, right click on the source code line after the loop and from the context menu select "Run to Cursor".

Alternatively set the cursor to the line after the loop by left-clicking and press Ctrl+F10 on the keyboard to trigger the "Run to Cursor" command.